# Plotting pandas boxplots next to each other in iPython Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to print three pandas boxplots next to each other in iPython Notebook.

The dataframes each look basically like this:

```
sub    cond   accuracy
s1     A      0.814868
s2     A      0.504574
s3     A      0.438314
s4     A      0.956235
s5     A      0.370771
s1     B      0.228724
s2     B      0.691374
s3     B      0.237314
s4     B      0.32633
s5     B      0.859961
```

When I plot accuracy without subsetting by condition, this works great:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3]):
    df.boxplot('accuracy',ax=axes[i])
```

However, when I try to plot accuracy by condition for each dataframe using instead:

`df.boxplot('accuracy',by='cond',ax=axes[i])`

only the last plot displays (and not where it should be according to its axes assignment).

What's going on? Is there a better way to plot boxplots like this next to each other in iPython Notebook?

Comment: This looks like a bug.

Comment: @PhillipCloud - do you have a sense of whether it's a bug in pandas or ipython notebook?

Comment: It's pandas. Same thing happens on the command line

Comment: It's quite likely a bug, if you add a line of `print plt.gca()` in the loop you can see once you have the `by=`, it ignores the `subplot` `axes`

Comment: In the same Jupyter notebook, I had this plotting of boxplots with a for loop work for one thing and fail for another..